# Remove values ending with specific character in R

Tags: r

Can we remove a values in a column ending with specific values in R. For example can we remove values ending with df and sa below. df is a dataframe

```
df
ColA
asdf
fdsa
adss
sasa
fdsa
dfdf
```

Expected output

```
df
ColA
adss
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use :

```
subset(df, !grepl("(df|sa)$", ColA))
#  ColA
#3 adss
```

A faster option would be :

```
subset(df, !(endsWith(ColA, 'df') | endsWith(ColA, 'sa')))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("asdf", "fdsa", "adss", "sasa", "fdsa", 
"dfdf")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks but it removes even if the word contains df or sa. I need to remove only ending with df  or sa :)

Comment: @imranp Can you show me an example?  If I change `df$ColA[4] <- 'saab'` it doesn't remove it.

Comment: @imranp Hi...did you check the answer? Did it work for you? Do you have cases where the answer fails? If it works as expected please consider to accept the answer by clicking on checkmark next to the vote button so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- c(
    "ColA",
    "asdf",
    "fdsa",
    "adss",
    "sasa",
    "fdsa",
    "dfdf")
grep("(df|sa)$", x, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
[1] "ColA" "adss"
```